# Do some people in 3D holograms doing the same things somewhere else in real life?

Tags: hologram

This question is about 3D holograms.

I watched a few videos about holograms on youtube.On [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGkyDkDmZts) of them there was a teacher who visits the class via hologram for a few minutes.I know that they made  holograms of even dead people like Michael Jackson. But I would like to ask if  it technically possible  , what people in the real life can be seen as a hologram in somewhere else. It could be like video phone but while person A sees video of the other side, the other side can see person A as a hologram.

(sorry for grammar mistakes, English is not my native language.)

Comment: What do you know about the process in which holograms are produced?

Comment: @Sean not much mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, they are not holograms. They are a modern derivative of an old stage magic trick called [Pepper's Ghost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper%27s_ghost)

> The basic trick involves a stage that is specially arranged into two
>   rooms, one that people can see into or the stage as a whole, and a
>   second that is hidden to the side, the "blue room." A plate of glass
>   (or plexiglas or plastic film) is placed somewhere in the main room at
>   an angle that reflects the view of the blue room towards the audience.

The modern version uses a monitor or projector.
Here is the manga character and vocaloid software [Hatsune Miku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O17f3lB7BFY) - you can almost see how it's done (the 45 degree screen is vertical and supported by the columns either side of her.

Answer (score -1):

There are now glasses you can purchase that have tiny cameras that project the light onto the glasses's lenses to create a hologram.  Check out Augmented Reality glasses, there are many manufacturers that are making them and they have gotten pretty powerful in the last year or 2.  They are also starting to come down in price.  For the holograms of real people that appear somewhere else there is a technology called volumetric capture that positions hundreds of cameras around a stage that feed the images to a computer that stitches the images into a 3d representation.  That representation can then be sent via internet to another location and can be viewed with the AR headsets or other methods mentioned in other answers.